# How to find the relationship between parameters and eigenvalue via DEigensystem or NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have a system with some parameters(like masses,couplings). But it seems DEigensystem/NDEigensystem only works when theses parameters are specified? My code is below:

```
couple = {0.298, 0.222};
mass = {0.5745, 0.0112};
V11[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(6/x^2 - 6/x^3);
V12[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(96*3.14*couple[[1]])/x^5;
V13[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(96*3.14*couple[[2]])/x^5;
V21[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(144*couple[[1]])/x^5;
V22[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(6/x^2 (1 + (576*3.14*(couple[[1]])^2)/x^6) + 2/
     x^3 + (mass[[1]])^2);
V23[x_] = 0;
V31[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(144*couple[[2]])/x^5;
V32[x_] = 0;
V33[x_] = (1 - 2/x)*(1 - 
     2/x)*(6/x^2 (1 + (576*3.14*(couple[[2]])^2)/x^6) + 2/
     x^3 + (mass[[2]])^2);
eq1 = -(1 - 2/x)^2 g''[x] - (2/x^2 - 4/x^3) g'[x] + V11[x]*g[x] + 
   V12[x]*s1[x] + V13[x]*s2[x];
eq2 = -(1 - 2/x)^2 s1''[x] - (2/x^2 - 4/x^3) s1'[x] + V21[x]*g[x] + 
   V22[x]*s1[x];
eq3 = -(1 - 2/x)^2 s2''[x] - (2/x^2 - 4/x^3) s2'[x] + V31[x]*g[x] + 
   V33[x]*s2[x];
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {g[x], s1[x], s2[x]}, {x, 2, 100}, 10]
```

In fact, I hope to know when this system has complex eigenvalues.

Comment: `NDEigensystem` is a numerical function that in fact needs all numerical values to operate. `DEigensystems` should be able to operate symbolically, but then again not everything can be solved symbolically.